# Regex Replace Not Matching

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a regex to strip anything that's not a hex character or a comma.

I have the below code:

```
$hex = "hex:68,65,6C,6C,6F,\
  73,74,61,63,6B,6F,76,65,72,66,6C,6F,77,\
  72,65,68,65,78,70,65,72,74,73"

#remove superfluous characters
$hex = $hex -replace "[0-9A-F]{2}|,",""
Write-Output $hex
```

Which gives the below output:

```
hex:\
  \
```

I'd like the opposite (i.e. to remove the characters displayed above, and keep those previously stripped).  I'm aware that `[^`*pattern*`]` negates a pattern; but so far I've been unsuccessful in making reality match that theory / can't figure out how this work's when you're dealing with a full pattern rather than single characters...

Desired Output:

```
68,65,6C,6C,6F,73,74,61,63,6B,6F,76,65,72,66,6C,6F,77,72,65,68,65,78,70,65,72,74,73
```

**Regex 101:** http://regex101.com/r/xJ3yU6/1

Attempts so far:

- [^[0-9A-F]{2},?]
- [^(?:[0-9A-F]{2}),?]
- [^(?:[0-9A-F]{2})][^,]
- [^(?:[0-9A-F]{2}|,)]
- [^(?:[0-9A-F]{2},?)]
- [^0-9A-F]{2}[^,?]
- various others getting less and less valid / too shamefully so to post.

NB: If there's a good powershell solution instead of the regex one I'd also be interested; though I suspect regex would be the more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would have captured and kept all the stuff you wanted, and then matched (but not captured) all the rest:

```
Search:
([0-9A-F]{2}|,)|.

Replace:
$1
```

That will leave you with the result of:

```
68,65,6C,6C,6F,73,74,61,63,6B,6F,76,65,72,66,6C,6F,77,72,65,68,65,78,70,65,72,74,73
```

You can see this [on Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xJ3yU6/2). Notice that I used the `s` flag so the `.` character will also match newline characters.

Comment: That's perfect - not sure why I didn't think of that... thank-you.  `$hex = $hex -replace "([0-9A-F]{2}|,)|.|\s",'$1'`

Answer (score 2):

I had to look around a bit as well. You cannot easily do this with a replace, unless you do it using capturing groups, which, doesn't yield exactly what you're after...

```
$hex = "hex:68,65,6C,6C,6F,\
  73,74,61,63,6B,6F,76,65,72,66,6C,6F,77,\
  72,65,68,65,78,70,65,72,74,73"

$hex = $hex -replace "hex:((?:[a-f0-9]{2},?)*).*", '$1'
Write-Output $hex
```

This works better by selecting what to keep

```
$hex = "hex:68,65,6C,6C,6F,\
  73,74,61,63,6B,6F,76,65,72,66,6C,6F,77,\
  72,65,68,65,78,70,65,72,74,73"

$hex = ($hex | select-string -allmatches "(?<=[:,](\\\s*)?)[a-f0-9]{2}").Matches -join(",")
Write-Output $hex
```

Where your regex 101 goes wrong is that `[^regexhere]` is actually looking for a single character that is none of these: `{'r','e','g','x','h'}`. It is a placeholder for a single value and it doesn't actually mean "this word", there is a way to do that too, but it's harder to use `(?!hex:)` this looks if the next 4 characters are the word `hex:`, but doesn't actually capture them. I'm usign the opposite of that in the second solution, where I say: "any hexadecimal number that is preceded by a `,` or `:`, but I'm not interested in the `,` and `:` themselves".

Comment: Great solution and explanation; very much appreciated - thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why don't you simply remove what you *don't* want in the string instead of trying to *not* remove everything you want?

```
PS C:\> $hex = "hex:68,65,6C,6C,6F,\
>>   73,74,61,63,6B,6F,76,65,72,66,6C,6F,77,\
>>   72,65,68,65,78,70,65,72,74,73"
>>
PS C:\> $hex
hex:68,65,6C,6C,6F,\
  73,74,61,63,6B,6F,76,65,72,66,6C,6F,77,\
  72,65,68,65,78,70,65,72,74,73
PS C:\> $hex -replace '^hex:' -replace '\\\s*'
68,65,6C,6C,6F,73,74,61,63,6B,6F,76,65,72,66,6C,6F,77,72,65,68,65,78,70,65,72,74,73
```

Comment: Good point.  My reasoning here was just that I know what I want, but I'm not sure of what else there could be (the single example I've seen implies that your solution would be correct - but I like to avoid assumptions as much as possible (within reason)).